# Date.getTime() is not a function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in Typescript:

```
var period = self.getPeriod(someObject.createdTime);

//createdTime is of the type Date


getPeriod(date: Date){
  let today = new Date();
  today.getTime(); // works fine
  date.getTime(); // date.gettime() is not a function

  //rest of the code removed 

}
```

What am I doing wrong? If I try to pass string in someObject.createdTime.ToUTCString(), it throws createdTime.toUTCString() is not a function.

Comment: Make sure `someObject.createdTime`  is actually a date. Check that the output of `Object.prototype.toString.call(someObject.createdTime)` equals something like `[object Date]` ...

Comment: Yes you are right. Although at compile time, its a Date object but at runtime its a string object. If I treat it as string at compile time, typescript throws compile error. How can I get around this?

Comment: @Padhi... Try logging `Object.keys(someObject)` inside the function and see what properties u get...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: `new Date(date).getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var period = self.getPeriod(new Date());

getPeriod(date: Date){
  let today = new Date();
  today.getTime(); 
  date.getTime(); 
}
```

Comment: How will I use if the parameter passed to the getPeriod method is retrieved from another data.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.